# Define operations to do in specific breakpoints using GDB

Tags: gdb

In `gdbinit` I defined some breakpoints.

How can I do that when specific breakpoint called I want to run `x/s $r1` ?

Answer (score -1):

I think your question is similar to an old (solved) thread on stackoverflow:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517423/how-to-do-an-specific-action-when-a-certain-breakpoint-is-hit-in-gdb